# What's the purpose of empty interfaces besides readability?

Tags: java, interface

Let me explain what I mean with an example.

I have the usual subscribe-post event system, where event handlers are methods with an annotation named `@EventHandler` or something (in my case it's `@EventSubscribe`, but whatevers), which have one argument whose type is a subclass of class `Event`

```
@EventHandler
public void onSomeEvent(SomeEvent event)
{
    //code here
}
```

Now, in other people's versions of the subscribe-post event system, I see an empty interface `Listener` or something similar, which as you can imagine is basically this:

```
public interface Listener {}
```

Classes extending `Listener` are expected to contain methods with `@EventHandler`, because their EventBus (or EventManager as they might call it) can only take `Listener` for their registry methods.

In my version, I have tried just ditching the `Listener` idea and let my EventBus take Objects for their registry methods, which does work just as well as far as I've tried.

Now, I understand that having a `Listener` interface would make it easier to read as classes extending them are instantly identified as containing Event handlers, but I was just wondering if there were any other benefits to them, because so far I can totally live without that kind of interface.

PS: For future reference, is there a special name for an empty interface, or an empty interface that is used in this manner?

Comment: Google *marker interface*.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hey, thanks. Now I'm certainly sure this is a duplicate question now that I know what the thing is even called.